# Get HTTP request and tolerate 500 server error in powershell

Tags: powershell, http-request

In Powershell v3.0 I would like to return the response code from an HTTP GET, such as `200 OK` or `500 Internal Server Error`. (This is for a hack-deploy to do a quick warmup of a deployed site and see if it works, a sort of a mini acceptance test. The status code is truly all I want.)

Against my wishes, `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` throws an error when it receives a `500 Internal Server Error`. This is annoying because it isn't really an error to me in my use case. Anyway, I figured I could catch the exception and still peel out the underlying response code, but I'm having trouble with that.

Here's some almost-working code:

```powershell
function WebResponseStatusCode (
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $url
) {
    $req = [system.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)
    try {
        $res = $req.GetResponse();
        $statuscode = $res.statuscode;
    }
    catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        #the outer error is a System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord
        Write-Host "error!"
        return = $_.Response.statuscode; #nope
    }
    finally {
        if (!($res -eq $null)) {
           $res.Close();
        }
    }
   return $statuscode;
}
```

The problem is of course that `$_` has no `Response` property. Neither does `$_.InnerException`, even when cast:

```
return [System.Net.WebException]($_.InnerException)
```

I've played around with `$_ | Get-Member` and exploring all its properties. I thought `$_.TargetObject` had some promise but it doesn't appear to.

(**Update**) I also think I tried variations on `$_.Exception.Response` though may have gotten it wrong.

Getting just a response code seems like such a simple thing to do.

Comment: I've seen other folks run into this issue.  It should probably be logged as an enhancement request on http://connect.microsoft.com to not throw on 5xx status codes.

Comment: Do you see the same results with Invoke-WebRequest? I don't have a server that's delivering a 500 result to test against.

Comment: The strange thing is that `Invoke-WebRequest` handles these errors differently from for example `Test-Connection` (i.e. ping). `Test-Connection` uses `-ErrorVariable` and `-ErrorAction` as you would expect. `Invoke-WebRequest` just calls `Write-Error` when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's an example, though it does a couple more things to allow you to test redirections as well as expected exceptions.

```powershell
function GetWebSiteStatusCode {
    param (
        [string] $testUri,
        $maximumRedirection = 5
    )
    $request = $null
    try {
        $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $testUri -MaximumRedirection $maximumRedirection -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    } 
    catch [System.Net.WebException] {
        $request = $_.Exception.Response

    }
    catch {
        Write-Error $_.Exception
        return $null
    }
    $request.StatusCode
}

GetWebSiteStatusCode -testUri "https://www.google.com/"
GetWebSiteStatusCode -testUri "https://www.google.com/foobar"
GetWebSiteStatusCode -testUri "http://google.com/" -maximumRedirection 0
GetWebSiteStatusCode -testUri "https://accounts.google.com" -maximumRedirection 0
GetWebSiteStatusCode -testUri "https://www.googleapis.com/coordinate/v1/teams/1/custom_fields?fields=1111&key="
GetWebSiteStatusCode -testUri "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/test/products/sasdf/asdf/asdf?key="

#Next test would be for an expected 500 page.
#GetWebSiteStatusCode -testUri "https://www.somesite.com/someurlthatreturns500"
```

Comment: This is great. I knew there had to be a way to do it more easily. It's too bad that you still have to catch an exception, but at least it's working! I don't know why my tries at using `$_.Exception.Response` didn't work.

Comment: Note that the exception returns a `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`, not a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject`, and in my tests, the response stream seems to have already been read.

Comment: I have tried this and it seems to work for most error codes. However, when I should be receiving a 12029 (system cannot locate the resource specified) code, this gives me a 0... please advise

Comment: Nice... The trick is to cast the caught exception to a WebException